# Select MySQL table with dynamic content

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of tables that are like Client# and the # changes. Is there a way to create a query to query that table based on the client number you get from logging in as their use?

Example to give idea:

```
      $q2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($q2,$conn);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $_CLIENT_ID = $row['CLIENTID'];
        $q2 = "SELECT * FROM client+".$_CLIENT_ID."";
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm trying to keep clients in their own tables so they do not get to massive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm trying to keep clients in their own tables so they do not get to massive.*

This is almost always the wrong strategy.  The table size isn't as important as how you have indexed it for access, and it can be [partitioned](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) later, should that become necessary.  The proper way to handle this is simply a column in one table which identifies the client id.

With a proper client-identifying column you can query as:

```
SELECT othertable.* 
FROM
  users 
  JOIN othertable ON users.CLIENTID = othertable.CLIENTID
WHERE users.username = '$_SESSION['username']'
```

Dealing with dynamic table names becomes troublesome not only because it is more difficult to query against.  You cannot, for example, use a placeholder in place of a table name with many parameterized query APIs like PDO & MySQLi:

```
// Won't work with a PDO prepared statement.  :clienttable place holder isn't allowed
SELECT * FROM :clienttable WHERE value=:someval
```